# Как выйти из git log?

Tags: git

Написал в git `git log` Мне вывело несколько моих коммитов, и потом при нажатиии enter выходит ещё коммит, и так пока коммиты не закончатся. И даже после этого я не могу написать в гите другую команду, висит end. Приходится перезапускать git bash. Как выйти из лога коммитов?

Comment: как [вариант](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483757/how-to-exit-git-log)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

По-умолчанию Git посылает вывод своих комманд на программу-pager. По-умолчанию это программа less. Выйти из less можно пятью способами: <kbd>q</kbd>,<kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> и <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.

Comment: Примечание: не забудьте переключить раскладку! Русское Й не сработает как надо!

Answer (score 5):

как и отовсюду комбинацией клавиш (это linux)
`CTRL + Z`

На виндовом клиенте не работает , поэтому что бы прекратить скрол нажмите `q`

Comment: CTRL + Z не выходит из программы, a приостанавливает программу и посылает ее в фон (вернуть ее обратно можно с помощью команды fg).

Comment: Спасибо! буду знать !

Answer (score 3):

Можно разными способами выйти из просмотра логов `git log`:

1. HotKey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
2. HotKey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>
3. Ввести <kbd>Q</kbd> и нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Аналогичная проблема была. НА вин 10, версии 2.18.0 выход кнопкой q работает отлично

Comment: Укажите просмоторщик, которым вы пользуетесь.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщение содержится решение, но не помешает все таки указать название приложение, как рекомендует 0xdb

Answer (score 1):

В моем случае выше перечисленные методы не работают. Помогло ctr+break (win 10)

Comment: А какой в вашем случае стоит просмоторщик?

Comment: Золотой вы человек